# Is SQLite suitable for use as a read only cache on a web server?

Tags: performance, sqlite, concurrency

I am currently building a high traffic GIS system which uses python on the web front end.  The system is 99% read only.  In the interest of performance, I am considering using an externally generated cache of pre-generated read-optimised GIS information and storing in an SQLite database on each individual web server.  In short it's going to be used as a distributed read-only cache which doesn't have to hop over the network.  The back end OLTP store will be postgreSQL but that will handle less than 1% of the requests.

I have considered using Redis but the dataset is quite large and therefore it will push up the administrative cost and memory cost on the virtual machines this is being hosted on.  Memcache is not suitable as it cannot do range queries.

Am I going to hit read-concurrency problems with SQLite doing this?

Is this a sensible approach?

Comment: This may well be the first case I've ever seen where SQLite *is* the most sensible approach.

Comment: The SQLite tables are updated periodically with data from the central postreSQL database?

Comment: No - they will come from a separate offline database and generated as and when the source data changes which is likely to be quarterly.  They will then be uploaded to the web servers, the files swapped and then the mod-wsgi instances restarted.  Basically - no writes, just files being swapped out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok after much research and performance testing, SQLite is suitable for this.  It has good request concurrency on static data.  SQLite only becomes an issue if you are doing writes as well as heavy reads.

More information here:

http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

Answer (score -3):

if usage case is just a cache why don't you use something like 
http://memcached.org/.

You can find memcached bindings for python in pypi repository.

Another options is that you use materialized views in postgres, this way you will keep things simple and have everything in one place.

http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views

Comment: The original poster said: "Memcache is not suitable as it cannot do range queries."

Comment: Memcached is unsuitable as stated.  I'm actually proposing materialized views but generated from a back end Postgres into a SQLite data file which takes about 4 hours including all the math that goes on.  I'd rather not put it into a single DB engine as I'll have to scale up rather than scale out which is expensive.  Once place is one all your eggs in one basket.  Also network traffic is likely to be expensive (compared to CPU<->memory<->disk).